# Eclipse Plugin as development environment for a programming language

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm going to write an eclipse plugin to support the development of simple scripts in an assembler language.
The GUI should be the same as you see writing java, at least a navigation-widget on the side and some text-highlighting.

My questions are:

1. What framework should I use? Is there even an alternative to OSGi/ Equinox?
2. What template should I use?
3. What else should I know about before I get started?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **Xtext** to generate an Editor for assembler language. Xtext needs a grammar and can generate a plugin with a fully functional editor, including *content assist*, *refactoring*, and much more.
2. there are already a lot of existing Xtext grammars, and probably you can find an existing Assembler grammar for Xtext. In this case, creating your editor it will be very easy, as long as you understand how Xtext works.
3. You should learn how to use Xtext (https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). You could read the online docs, find a good tutorial, or read a book about Xtext. I bought this ebook: [Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend. (2nd edition)](http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2016/07/the-forthcoming-second-edition-of-the-xtext-book/)

Comment: Will do. Thank you.